# Psycopg2 - copy_expert permission denied error

Tags: python, ubuntu, psycopg2

I'm attempting to make the switch from Windows to ubuntu (am using 12.04 LTS) and am trying to use some of my old scripts to run my old databases.
Previously I used postgresql and psycopg2 to maintain them and I am trying to do so again here.

My error is around importing a csv file to a table using the copy expert command.

Code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import psycopg2 as psy
import sys

conn = psy.connect("dbname, user, host, password") # with the appropriate  values
curs = conn.cursor()

table = 'tablename' # a table with the appropriate columns etc
file = 'filename' # a csv file
SQL = "COPY %s FROM '%s' WITH CSV HEADERS" % (tablename, filename)

curs.copy_expert(SQL, sys.stdin) # Error occurs here

conn.commit()
curs.close()
conn.close()
```

The specific error which is occurring is as follows:

> > psycopg2.ProgrammingError: could not open file "filename" for reading: Permission denied

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated:

I am completely stuck and I believe it is due some quirk of how I've set up the database or the files.

Adding a simple read and print command using the csv module works fine as well (from the same script in fact) It will output all of the information from the csv file and then error out with the permission denied when attempting to import it to the database

```
import csv
f = open(filename, 'rb')
read = csv.reader(f, delimiter =',')
for row in read:
    print row
f.close()
```

Comment: do you need to execute the script using `su` as the permission system is different between ubuntu and windows, you tend to need to execute commands using `sudo` unless you are the root user.

Comment: Same error when prefacing the command with sudo. In this case I am the root user. Could you please clarify how to preface it with su? as in su python script.py?

Comment: yes with `su` or `sudo` but it sounds like that will not work also, what happens if you copy the csv file to the desktop or other location that you definitely know you have full permissions to do whatever you like with the file? Also what is the path to filename, it is possible the path is incompatible with *nix convention ie. forwards slashes `/` instead of `\\` but this is normally taken care of by python.

Comment: Hi Ed, adding it to the home directory seemed to take care of the issue, the file was imported to the database successfully. I'm still a little unsure why. Perhaps something to do with the permissions of different superusers? E.g. postgres vs me? I was using a r"/home/nigel/<two more directories>" before, now using just /home/nigel the script worked successfully.

Comment: not sure why either but certain directories are locked down by default so you always either have to switch user or be the super user, it could just be that the location is still out of bounds for all users perhaps, anyway glad it sorted you out I will post a summary of my comments as an answer so you can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try executing the command as the super user by using `su` or `sudo` and if this doesn't help, the other possiblity is that the location of the filename is out of bounds so I would try copying it to the desktop or your home directory or folder where you know you definitely have full permissions and see if this works.

Comment: Cheers Ed, adding the file to the home folder solved the issue.