# psycopg2 is denied permissions on /tmp

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, ubuntu-12.04, psycopg2

When running a `copy` command via psycopg2 I get the error

`psycopg2.ProgrammingError: could not open file "/tmp/<>.txt" for writing: Permission denied`

I don't know the etiology of the issue, but in the past I have been able to run copy commands without this problem. Unlike the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10065926/psycopg2-copy-expert-permission-denied-error), changing the output location to home folder doesn't change the result. I've tried resetting the `/tmp` permissions with `chmod -R 777 /tmp`, but with no success. Running the script with sudo permissions hasn't worked either. What should I try next to troubleshoot this issue?

A code sample for the procedure is:

```
import psycopg2 as post
con = post.connect(<dbname>, <host>, <user>, <password>)
cur = con.cursor()
with open('/tmp/out_path.txt', 'w') as f:
    cur.copy_expert("COPY <table> TO '/tmp/out_path.txt' WITH CSV HEADER" + 
                    "DELIMITER AS E'\t'", f)
# close connections, etc
```

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 server, PostgreSQL 9.3, Python 2.7. Both the client and the host are on the same machine - I'm running the script while logged in via ssh.

Comment: Can you add to the question the code and the query you're using. Just a couple of lines, even without context.

Comment: Are the client and server on the same machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open('/tmp/out_path.txt', 'w') as f:
    cur.copy_expert("""
        COPY <table> TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER AS E'\t'
    """, f)
```

[From the docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html):

> The sql statement should be in the form COPY table TO STDOUT to export table to the file object passed as argument

Comment: Guess I went through the docs too quickly or had a case of expert mind. In the beginner’s mind there are many possibilities, but in the expert’s there are few.